# Make permission methods in Django admin more DRY

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two `ModelAdmin`s in my `admin.py`.

Each have the exact same permission methods (`has_view_permission`, `has_add_permission`, `has_change_permission`, `has_delete_permission`, `has_module_permission`).

Is there a way I could make this more DRY?

`admin.py`:

```
class FirstAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'title',
        'author'
    )

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True


class SecondAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'category',
    )

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True

    def has_module_permission(self,request):
        if request.user.is_admin:
            return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that using a class mixin, I've also managed to reduce the method body to one line.

Here's how:

```
class AdminUserPermissionMixin:
    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_admin

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.is_admin

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_admin

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_admin

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.is_admin



class FirstAdmin(AdminUserPermissionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'title',
        'author'
    )



class SecondAdmin(AdminUserPermissionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'category',
    )
```